# how to compare date parts in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a bit tricky question. E.g. I have a start_date: 15/01/2015 and an end date: 17/03/2015 for given record and I would like to generalize that to know,  if the record with those exact start and end date belongs to January (by my definition even if it is 31/01/2015, then it belongs to January).

I did the following:

```
sum(case when to_date('2015/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') between ROUND(dtime_method_start,'MONTH') and ROUND(dtime_method_end,'MONTH') then 1 else 0 end) as flag_jan
```

But the problem with Round function is, that it takes everything from 16-31 as next month, which is no good for me. How can I fix it or rewrite it to make it comply with my definition?

I want to know if a record with certain dtime_method_start and dtime_method_end belongs to January. I have many records with many different start and end dates and want to know how many of them belong to January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `trunc` instead of `round`. `Trunc` with parameter `'MONTH'` will truncate the date to the first day of month. If you test with `between` using first day of month it's ok.

Comment: Yep, that definitely helped! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT expected,
       CASE
           WHEN to_date('01/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') = ALL (trunc(start_date,'MONTH'), trunc(end_date,'MONTH'))
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END flag_jan
FROM
  (SELECT 'notmatch 0'                        expected
         , to_date('15/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') start_date
         , to_date('17/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
   FROM dual
  UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'match 1'
        , to_date('12/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
        , to_date('23/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
   FROM dual
  ) dates;
```

this query compares the truncated start_date and end_date to match the first day of the month.

To check another month_flag, juste change the date in the first case expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the stored dates directly to a range based on the input date, rather than applying a function to every date:

```
count(case when dtime_method_start >=            trunc(to_date('2015/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd'),'mm') 
            and dtime_method_start <  add_months(trunc(to_date('2015/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd'),'mm'),1)
           then 1
       end) as flag_jan
```

Or you could

```
count(case when trunc(dtime_method_start,'mm') = trunc(to_date('2015/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd'),'mm') 
           then 1
       end) as flag_jan
```

Comment: Thanks as well. The second solution was exactly what I were looking for.